# How can i import a html or xml-file in a Sandcastle project

Tags: html, xml, import, sandcastle

i have published a Class from Matlab as xml and html file. In an other project i have make a help file with the Sandcastle help file builder. Now i want to include the html/xml file in this project and it should be shown as one file. Is it a way to make this? I haven't find anything.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a conversiontool to convert from html to .aml. It is in the folder

`C:\Program Files (x86)\EWSoftware\Sandcastle Help File Builder\Extras`